# Error in Transport for helm install package

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install postgresql using helm on my kubernetes cluster.
I get error in transport when i run the helm install command.

I have tied different solutions online, none worked.

```
helm install --name realtesting stable/postgresql --debug
```

The expect result is a deployed postgresql on my kubernetes cluster

Please help!

Comment: did you deploy tiller server? share the error details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have not initialized helm with a service account.

In rbac-config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

**Step 1**: `kubectl apply -f rbac-config.yaml`

**Step 2**: `helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 200`

**Step 3**: Test the setup with `heml ls`. There would not be any output from running this command and that is expected. Now, you can run `helm install --name realtesting stable/postgresql`

Comment: ok, @rajesh. After doing all these, it worked but my pods remain in the pending state

Answer (score 0):

you need to deploy the tiller server.

then follow the below steps

```
master $ kubectl get po -n kube-system |grep tiller
tiller-deploy-5bcf6f5c7c-km8hn   1/1       Running   0          18s

master $ helm install --name realtesting stable/postgresql --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '32876'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:32876"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] Fetched stable/postgresql to /root/.helm/cache/archive/postgresql-4.0.1.tgz

[debug] CHART PATH: /root/.helm/cache/archive/postgresql-4.0.1.tgz

NAME:   realtesting
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Fri May 10 08:52:11 2019
CHART: postgresql-4.0.1
```

Comment: What is the questioner supposed to do differently?  The `helm install` command is exactly what they said they're already doing unsuccessfully.

Comment: For further debugging please use: `kubectl get events, 
kubectl get pv,pvc, 
kubectl describe pod <your postgresql pod>`